# Problem related to cyclic and abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group of order $3n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$. Suppose all the elements of $G$ of order $3$ are conjugate. Then which are true?

1. G must be cyclic.
2. G cannot be abelian
3. G must be abelian and not cyclic
4. G must be abelian and may or may not be cyclic.

   Since all the  elements of order $3$ are conjugate, then there is a unique normal $3$-Sylow subgroup. If I take $G=S_3$, then (1) is false. But I have no idea about other, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about conjugate elements in Abelian groups.

Comment: I cant understand sir ,please explain

Comment: If there were an element of order 3, as would be the case if $G$ were abelian, then there would be at least two elements of order 3. Thus, you would have two different elements that are conjugates.

Answer (score 1):

$S_3$ is a counter example to 1),3) and 4), as you have said already,. because $S_3$ is not abelian, and hence also not cyclic. For 2) consider the cyclic group $C_3$.